# null sequences in $L^{\infty}([0,1])$

Tags: normed-spaces

I am trying to unsterstand the subtle difference between $L^p$ $p < \infty$ spaces and $L^\infty$. 
Is it possible to construct a sequence $f_k$ in $L^{\infty}([0,1])$ such that $\|f_k\|_{L^p} \to 0$, but $\|f_k\|_{L^\infty} \not\to 0$?

Or can you proof $\|f_k\|_{L^\infty} \le C \|f_k\|_{L^p}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one has a trivial counterexample, take $f_k(x)= x^k$. Clearly, $\|f_k, L^\infty(0,1)\| = 1$ and $\|f_k, L^p(0,1)\| = \left(\frac{1}{kp+1}\right)^{1/p}$, hence $f_k\to0$ in $L^p$.

This counterexample also works for the second part of the question.

On a conceptual level, an $L^p$ function (for $1\le p < \infty$) can have an arbitrarily bad behavior in terms of its $L^\infty$-norm (if that norm exists at all).